What ID number do I use on a Schengen visa application form?
I live in Israel as a caregiver with a B1 visa. I am planning to visit Italy but I am having difficulties filling in point number 20 on the Schengen visa application form. It asks for a permit number or equivalent number. I have no residence permit; I only have a visa.
What should I mention there?

Do you not have an Israeli ID number? Are you legally employed?

Yes I am legal  employee

So you should have a national id, use that.

The Israeli B1 visa would be the best choice because it includes both a number and expiration date.  It will also need to marked as a multiple entry visa as proof of intent to return. Applying for a Schengen visa

Okay thank you for helping

The full question in the application form is:


Residence in a country other than the country of current nationality:

□ No
□ Yes. Residence permit or equivalent ……………………………… No. …………………………………....... Valid until……………

Enter your visa number, or, as @littleadv states in a comment, your Israeli national ID#.
